# How to load a different json file into different json object using node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm new to Json and node.js

I'm trying load my json file into a jsonobject using node.js. 
But I'm unable to do so.

I've created 2 files one is `server.js` and `jsonresponse.json`. I need to load the `jsonresponse.json` in json object created in `server.js` using javascript or node.js.
This is snippet of `server.js`

```
var file = 'jsonresponse.json'
jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {

       jsonObject = console.dir(obj);
 })
```

Comment: Whilst it is well worth looking into manually reading a file stream with the `fs` module and parsing it yourself. If you `require()` the json file node will read and parse it for you. The downside is if there was an error parsing or reading it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose my json data is in `myDirectry/data.json`

```
//data.json
{
    "a":2,
    "b":3
}
```

So my `myDirectory/app.js` should be.

```
var x=require('./data');//or require('data');
console.log(x);
```

In order to read ,only `require()` is enough though u can read it using `fs`.But the best way is to `require`.

Answer (score 1):

While the following code will give you the object in procedural way you should keep in mind the asynchronous behaviour of node.

```
   var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
   var file = 'jsonresponse.json'
   var jsonObject = jsonfile.readFileSync(file)
```

As you are starting with node, you should get familiar with the [callback pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)#JavaScript)

In the snippet provided by you the file is being loaded in callback and you should be accessible within that scope.

```
   var file = 'jsonresponse.json';
   var jsonObject;
   jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, obj) {
       //on success obj is the data therefore it holds the reference to contents of the file
       if(!err){
            jsonObject = obj;
       }
       else console.log(err);
   })
```

`jsonfile.readFile` is called withe the filename and a callback function. Once it completes the task of reading file it invokes the callback function with 2 parameters: `error` and `data`.

`error` is null if theres no problem, otherwise it contains the error details.

`data` contains whatever data the function wanted to return.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to avoid caching (file changes between calls) do this

```
var fs = require('fs')
var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('myfile.json').toString())
```